# 荷兰猪、天竺鼠、豚鼠 ——What's the deal?

Tags: phrase

So these terms for Guinea Pig all seem to be fairly common and in use, at least as far as I know, but the question(s) are:

where do the different terms come from?

is there any actual difference between the terms?

are the terms regional or not?!

Comment: Apparently 豚鼠 comes from its appearance. It is also the scientific term.

Comment: Regarding 荷兰猪, my speculation is that it was brought to China by Dutch merchants/colonists, and Chinese at that time didn't realise that it was rodent and thought it was a pig. They might think that the pigs in the Netherlands are different, because they are so small, hence giving the name 荷兰猪.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just nicknames.
There are no evidence about where these names come from, as I can see.
I found some explanations but I can't make sure they're true.

1. It is called 天竺鼠 because Indian businessmen brought them into China.
2. It is called 荷蘭豬 because it looks like a pig and its barking sounds like pigs' barking.
3. It is called 荷蘭豬 because it was eat by Dutch before.
4. It is called 豚鼠 because it is 鼠...

And *user58955* also provided some explanations. I don't think any of them is true... Just don't be too serious with these nicknames...